# How to convert the object to 2d array using javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6

I have an object like:

```
{
    "sample.JPG": {
        "id": "c9a29270",
        "filename": "sample.JPG"
    },
    "test.JPG": {
        "id": "c6a270",
        "filename": "test.JPG"
    },
    "sample1.JPG": {
        "id": "c70",
        "filename": "sample1.JPG"
    },
    "test2.JPG": {
        "id": "c6a",
        "filename": "test2.JPG"
    }
}
```

and want it to be like:

```
[["fakepath/sample.JPG", "c9a29270"], ["fakepath/test.JPG", "c6a270"]]
```

here fake path means nothing but a static/hardcoded path
what I tried was

```
Object.keys(myobj).map((key)=> {
    return myoby[key];
});
```

but the result was fit to my need any suggestions?

I did something like this:

```
for(var i in obj){
    this.arr.push(['fakepath/' + i,obj[i].id])
}
```

is it OK?

Comment: What do you mean by "OK"? Why not use it if this solves your problem?

Answer (score 3):

You can `map()` over [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Object/values) which is pretty concise and easier to read than a loop:

```js
let o = {"sample.JPG": {"id": "c9a29270","filename": "sample.JPG"},"test.JPG": {"id": "c6a270","filename": "test.JPG"},"sample1.JPG": {"id": "c70","filename": "sample1.JPG"},"test2.JPG": {"id": "c6a","filename": "test2.JPG"}}

let arr = Object.values(o).map(({id, filename}) => ['fakepath/' + filename, id])
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `Object.keys` and `map`.

```js
let obj = { "sample.JPG": { "id": "c9a29270", "filename": "sample.JPG" }, "test.JPG": { "id": "c6a270", "filename": "test.JPG" }, "sample1.JPG": { "id": "c70", "filename": "sample1.JPG" }, "test2.JPG": { "id": "c6a", "filename": "test2.JPG" } } 
console.log(Object.keys(obj).map(key=> [`fakepath/${key}`, obj[key].id]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the `Object.entries` of the object:

```js
const input = {
  "sample.JPG": {
    "id": "c9a29270",
    "filename": "sample.JPG"
  },
  "test.JPG": {
    "id": "c6a270",
    "filename": "test.JPG"
  },
  "sample1.JPG": {
    "id": "c70",
    "filename": "sample1.JPG"
  },
  "test2.JPG": {
    "id": "c6a",
    "filename": "test2.JPG"
  }
};
const output = Object.entries(input)
  .map(([key, { id, filename }]) => ([`fakepath/${filename}`, id]))
console.log(output);
```

Comment: i used a for in loop is it ok ?

Comment: You *can*, but the functional array/object methods are generally better - less code to write, more abstract, no need for manual iteration, etc

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const src = {
  "sample.JPG": {
    "id": "c9a29270",
    "filename": "sample.JPG"
  },
  "test.JPG": {
    "id": "c6a270",
    "filename": "test.JPG"
  },
  "sample1.JPG": {
    "id": "c70",
    "filename": "sample1.JPG"
  },
  "test2.JPG": {
    "id": "c6a",
    "filename": "test2.JPG"
  }
};

function objToAr(obj){
  let result = [];
   for(key in obj){
     let innerObj = obj[key];
     result.push([`fakepath/${innerObj.filename}`, innerObj.id]);
   }
  return result;
}

console.log(objToAr(src))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) with [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) by using the mapping function to map each object to an array with the path and the id:

```js
const obj = {"sample.JPG": {"id": "c9a29270","filename": "sample.JPG"},"test.JPG": {"id": "c6a270","filename": "test.JPG"},"sample1.JPG": {"id": "c70","filename": "sample1.JPG"},"test2.JPG": {"id": "c6a","filename": "test2.JPG"}}

const res = Array.from(Object.values(obj), 
  ({id, filename}) => [`fakepath/${filename}`, id]);

console.log(res);
```